# How do I create a callback in C# (.NET 4.5) for HttpClient.GetAsync(URI)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I'd like to create a simple, async request to Google search.

According to Google, the simplest way to do this is using their JSON API with the simple curl request

```
curl -e http://www.my-ajax-site.com \ 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton'
```

I'd like to pull the first 5 pages of results and add the URL's of each result to an array. I find it unbelievably difficult to find any well-explained tutorials on HttpClient.GetAsync.
I haven't got any further than this:

```
public String[] search(String term = "")
{
    var rq = new HttpClient();
    var uri = new Uri("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:" + term);
    rq.GetAsync(uri);
}
```

I suppose this should start a task so I won't block the main thread, but how do I register a callback method for when the request is completed?

Comment: Just do `rq.GetAsync(uri).Result` to wait for it.

Comment: @leppie I don't want to wait for it, I'm going to do this with another API as well where I might be running 10-15 threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await rq.GetAsync(uri);

//put here your continuation logic.
```

Comment: @TimeSheep What you mean? You don't `wait` you `await`. Read about `async/await` keywords.

Comment: Yes I realized that was a misconception... I'm going to try this and will pick the answer that does it for me once I get the time to finish it :)

Answer (score 7):

Since the GetAsync is a task you can do

```
     rq.GetAsync(uri).ContinueWith((requestTask) => SomeMethod(requestTask););
```

Comment: there is one more `;`,which causes syntax error, and it should be the below: 

    rq.GetAsync(uri).ContinueWith((requestTask) => SomeMethod(requestTask));

Comment: does this happen once the async task has finished?